# Подскажите способы решения данной задачи?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть слайдер , необходимо сделать вот такой эффект на картинку в правом нижнем углу.
Подскажите способы решения как на чистом **css** так и другие? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно не самое элегантное и правильное решение, но вот вариант:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid white
}
div::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -3%;
  right:-3%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.5), transparent 40%);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```